# Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Database will not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am working through the [Michael Hartl](http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/sign_in_out) tutorial

I have created a migration file called add_remember_token_to_users and filled it with the contents from listing 8.16 in order to create a remember_token cell, which is indexed, for each user.

I migrated the data, from the command line, which, according to the cmd, ran successfully. However, I am looking at the test.sqlite3 file with a splite browser and it has not updated to include a remember_token cell. What is going on?

I don't see any typos in my migration file and I generated the migration file using rails.

Comment: `db/schema.rb` might help point out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the migration to the test database as well, because the migration only updated the development database. You can achieve it using the following command:

```
rake db:test:clone_structure # Recreate the test databases from the development structure
```

Note that there are other ways to achieve the same results such as running just the `clone` if you are wondering:

```
db:test:clone
```

Comment: I checked the development database as well

Comment: what was the output in your console when you ran the `rake db:migrate` command ?

Comment: `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20141024165248 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrating ==========================
== 20141024165248 AddRememberTokenToUsers: migrated (0.0000s) =================`

Comment: That shows no changes were done, otherwise it would output a line similar to this: `add_column(:users, :remember_token, :string)` . update your question with the content of your migration file

Comment: Did you actually updated the migration file to add the column like this:  `add_column :users, :remember_token, :string` ?

Comment: that is odd, my migration file is correct; what could the cause be or how can I correct it? Is there a way to remove the migration file so I can try to regenerate it?

Comment: `class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end`

Comment: you can do a rollback `rake db:rollback` and then delete the migration file manually and generate again.

Comment: the database rollback failed because **Index name 'index_users_on_remember_token' on table 'users' does not existc:in `migrate'**. So I manually deleted the migration file, regenerated the file again but this time it was successful. I guess the original migration file generation was bad? Thx Ali

Comment: Error message makes sense since changes were not actually applied the first time. I Can't really say what went wrong the first time, All we can say for sure is that when you ran the migration no changes were done to the database, according to the output.

Comment: A simple reason could be you edited the migration file but you didn't save the changes before running the migration command :)

Comment: wouldn't rerunning the db migration apply those changes once they are saved?